# Export raster of CHM from lidR

Tags: lidr

I would like to use lidR to produce canopy height rasters. I was following along in the '[rasterizing perfect CHM](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/wiki/Rasterizing-perfect-canopy-height-models)' user guide and now I'm wondering how to export this raster to a GeoTiff or .img. In particular, I think I'm going to loop through each tile (of thousands) and produce a CHM using this line of code...

```
chm6 = grid_canopy(las, 0.25, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0,1), subcircle = 0.2))
```

Of course, I'll change the pixel size, etc. for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rasterizing perfect CHM is one of the wiki page of the `lidR` package. It shows how to process a `LAS` object. In `lidR` to process several tiles you can use a `LAScatalog`. You should also read the package vignette about the `LAScatalog` class [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lidR/vignettes/lidR-LAScatalog-class.html) or with `browseVignettes("lidR")`. You should also read the documentation of the `LAScatalog` class `?LAScatalog-class`. Once you have read all this stuff you will find yourself the different options:

The simplest one

```
ctg <- catalog("path/to/folder")
chm6 = grid_canopy(ctg, 0.25, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0,1), subcircle = 0.2))
```

You can tweak the size of the chunks to process chunks of 500x500 m

```
ctg <- catalog("path/to/folder")
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 500
chm6 = grid_canopy(ctg, 0.25, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0,1), subcircle = 0.2))
```

You can write the output of each chunk into a Geotiff file

```
ctg <- catalog("path/to/folder")
opt_chunk_size(ctg) <- 1000
opt_output_files(ctg) <- "path/to/folder/CHM_{XRIGHT}_{YBOTTOM}"
chm6 = grid_canopy(ctg, 0.25, pitfree(c(0,2,5,10,15), c(0,1), subcircle = 0.2))
```

You will find many other options reading the documentation including the documentation of `grid_canopy`.

That being said I hardly believe you can apply the `pitfree` algorithm on thousandth of files. It is a computationally demanding algorithms and the process is likely to run forever. But this is another question.